# Most efficient way to split an array to write to different files

Tags: arrays, c, fwrite

I'm reading `double` data in from a DAQ that has 2 channels. Data is stored in `read_buf`, the first `1000` samples are `channel 0` and the second `1000` are `channel 1`. I have no control over this concatenation of channel data.

I have set up 2 files like so,

```
FILE *fptr_0;
if ((fptr_0 = fopen("channel_0.bin", "wb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file.\n");
    exit(1);
}

FILE *fptr_1;
if ((fptr_1 = fopen("channel_1.bin", "wb")) == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file.\n");
    exit(1);
}
```

I would then like to split `read_buf` and send the first half to `fptr_0` and the second to `fptr_1`. I can read out the first half but am flummoxed on how to read out the second half. How do I point `fptr_1` to just the second half of `read_buf`?

Do I have to copy each half into a new array?

What I have so far which works for the first half followed by what I'm not getting,

```
double read_buf[2000];
result = DAQ_func(device, &status, read_buf);
fwrite(&read_buf, sizeof(double), (sizeof(read_buf) / sizeof(read_buf[0])) / 2, fptr_0);
fwrite( ??? , sizeof(double), (sizeof(read_buf) / sizeof(read_buf[0])) / 2, fptr_1);
```

Comment: Add definition of `read_buf`. Is it `double read_buf[2000];`?

Comment: Aside: How about a solution that works correctly first? Then you can worry about efficiency.

Comment: @i486 added definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`???` is `read_buf + 1000` (no &).

```
fwrite(read_buf + 1000, sizeof (double), (sizeof read_buf / sizeof read_buf[0]) / 2, fptr_1);
```

Or if you prefer `&read_buf[1000]` which is the same.

Answer (score 1):

> How do I point fptr_1 to just the second half of read_buf?

You do not want to point the `FILE *` to anything but the stream associated with the file.

```
fwrite( ??? , sizeof(double), (sizeof(read_buf) / sizeof(read_buf[0])) / 2, fptr_1);
```

Adding 1000 to `read_buf` will increment it by the sizeof it's contents.

So that gives us:

```
fwrite (read_buf + 1000, sizeof(double), (sizeof(read_buf) / sizeof(read_buf[0])) / 2, fptr_1);
```

Or:

```
fwrite (&read_buf[1000], sizeof(double), (sizeof(read_buf) / sizeof(read_buf[0])) / 2, fptr_1);
```

where `&read_buf[1000]` will yield a pointer to the 1001th element of the array.

Is this the most efficient way? Perhaps not, but it's correct.

The return value of `fwrite()` should be checked too:

> The fwrite() function shall return the number of elements
> successfully written, which may be less than nitems if a write
> error is encountered. If size or nitems is 0, fwrite() shall
> return 0 and the state of the stream remains unchanged.
> Otherwise, if a write error occurs, the error indicator for the
> stream shall be set, and errno shall be set to indicate the
> error.